# Make instance of class available to all classes in spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have a class which basically just contains a HashMap.

The class also has a simple getter method which allows other parts of my application to send the "key" and get back the value from the map.

That much works, however, I don't want to keep instantiating that class every time I need to access it, because this particular data doesn't really change, and I only want it in the map for the sake of querying it quickly for the value I need.

I would like my main application class to create an instance of this, and then have it be available to all of my other classes automatically.

I have been reading about this a lot this morning, but am kind of confused about how it could be achieved, am I trying to do some sort of singleton? Or am I trying to use a service?

Anyway, if anyone has a snippet I can learn from - that would really help me out. I am currently using Annotations for most stuff in spring, and would LIKE to keep it that way.

Comment: Spring beans are singletons by default. Just make it a Spring bean and inject it where you need it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may not even need a separate class to hold your map. Directly create a bean of the Map which you may want and then Autowire the map where ever you need them.

```
@Configuration
public class MapConfiguration {
    @Bean 
    public Map<String, Object> dataMap() {
        // Create and return your Map here
    }
}
```

Whereever you want your map, just use autowiring.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataMap")
private Map<String, Object> dataMap;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue to use Spring, you can use the `@Component` to create a simple component.  By default all components are singletons.  You can use the `@PostConstruct` to initialize the data.   Below is an example.  I'm using a `String` as the map key, but you can modify it to match your application.

```
@Component
public class MyMap {
    private Map<String, Object> theMap = new HashMap<>();

    // PostConstruct runs after the application context instantiates the bean
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // initialize the data in theMap
    }

    public Object get(String key) {
        return theMap.get(key);
    }
 }
```

You can then use the `@Autowired` annotation or your application context to retrieve the bean:

```
public class AnotherClass {
    @Autowired
    MyMap myMap;
    // ...
}
```

If you would like to avoid Spring, another option is to create a simple Java singleton.  Here's an example

```
public class MyMap {
    private final static Map<String, Object> theMap = new HashMap<>();

    // Use a static block to initialize the map with data
    static {
         // populate theMap with data
    }

    public Object get(String key) {
        return theMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

One thing to note is that if your map ever does actually get updated, then you will need to handle concurrent reads and updates.

Comment: Ok, I think I get how the Component stuff makes it a singleton -but then how do I access that singleton in different classes? Do I do some sort of Autowired annotation or something? How do I make the first instance? So many questions! sorry :P

Comment: @IWishIWasABarista Yes, you can use the `@Autowired` annotation to inject it into another class.  The instance will be created the first time the spring application context needs to inject it into another bean.